# The value of span is not changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why this code is not working? I'm trying to change the value of span.

```
function timer(){
    var timer = $('#timer').val();
    if(timer!=''){
    $('#timer').html('HALO');
    }
}

timer();
setInterval(timer, 100);

<span id="timer"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

span doesn't have a `value`. It has `text` or `html`. 
You need  `var timer = $('#timer').html();`

Comment: Thank you! It works. I will allow this answer in 11 minutes :)